# По какому принципу работает скрытие новостей как в ВК

Tags: php, sql

Хотелось бы узнать, по какому принципу работает скрытие новостей как в ВК, то есть куда-то заносится **список ID** тех, кого не показывать, а потом обрабатывается. Можно конечно записываться их в таблицу users в поле hide_news через запятую, а потом в sql `NOT IN ARRAY(1,2,3)`. Но это не хорошо в плане ресурсов.

Может кто-то объяснит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как там сделано - не ведаю, но использовать список не правильно с точки зрения нормализации. Я бы создал таблицу с ключом {user_id, news_id}.

Comment: @msi, а можно чуть подробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: Что именно?

user_id - внешний ключ к таблице юзеров,

news_id - внешний ключ к таблице новостей.

Стандартная реализация связи "многие ко многим".

Comment: @msi, в user_id мне записывать id того, кто скрыл, а в news_id - id новости, которую скрыть?

Comment: @ModaL, в самом простом случае - да, если таблица только для скрытия будет использоваться. Но например можно ещё добавить столбец статуса - скрытие только там-то или ещё что-то, что сумеете сфантазировать.

Comment: @ModaL,
Ну, для кого вы это планировали:
NOT IN ARRAY(1,2,3)